# DatabaseCleaner + RSpec : what is the correct configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, database-cleaner

I included `database_cleaner` gem in my rails app. Followed the example given on the git repo and included the following code in `spec_helper`  :

Approach 1

```
  config.before(:suite) do
   DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
   DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
   DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
    example.run
   end
  end
```

When i run the `rspec` i get error as `NoMethodError:undefined method 'cleaning' for DatabaseCleaner:Module`.

So i did some research and found that i could replace the `config.around` block above with something like this :

Approach 2

```
config.before(:each) do
 DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
 DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

OR

Approach 3

```
config.around(:each) do |example|
  DatabaseCleaner.start
  example.run
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Both Approach 2 and 3 work well.
I also looked in the git repo of database_cleaner and found that `cleaning` method actually exists and with the following code :

```
def cleaning(&block)
     start
     yield
     clean
   end
```

which is exactly same as what i did in example 3. If it does exists then why is it not accessible?  Am i missing something here. Any more setup?
Or is Approach  2 or 3 preferable?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Finally found the answer,

`database_cleaner` gem added the `cleaning` method just last week and also updated the documentation for the same. BUT this change is not available in latest gem version 1.2.0 which I sourced from rubygems.org. `Approach 1` works perfectly when i source the gem from `github` as below:

```
gem 'database_cleaner', git: 'git@github.com:DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner.git'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the approach in the documentation if you pull the gem from Github

`gem 'database_cleaner', git: 'git@github.com:bmabey/database_cleaner.git'`

Comment: Thats what i did for it to work. Check my answer above.

Comment: I know.  Just extracted the actual Gemfile entry for lazy people ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you have this same issue using mongoid you can add this to Gemfile, change version to suit you, and run bundle install.

```
gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.4.1'
```

Then create a support folder in

```
spec/support/database_cleaner.rb
```

Require database_cleaner.rb in your spec_helper file, I use `gem 'require_all'` like so:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
require 'require_all'

require_rel 'support'
```

Add the following cleaners to database_cleaner.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  # Cleanup the DB in between test runs
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner[:mongoid].clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

Your tests should now tear down properly.