# Testing Rails on Ruby with rspec -- it takes too long because of TRUNCATE tables on loading rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, database-cleaner

I'm newbie in Ruby and Rails. I just started to work with both.

The application I'm working on uses `rspec` to run the tests in Ruby on Rails and at each round all the database tables are truncated. Tailing `log/test.log` displays many lines with `TRUNCATE TABLE <table>`. I see many posts that uses `Database cleaner` gem with configurations like:

```
config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
end
```

that would skip TRUNCATE tables. Or more comprehensive configurations like:

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :transaction
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
end

config.before(:all) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:all) do

  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

but it doesn't work.

There are other posts that suggests to set `fsync=off` in Postgres configuration, other tutorial suggests to set `full_page_writes=off` too. But I didn't fiund anything about MySQL, the DBMS I'm using.

Is there a similar configuration for MySQL?

Comment: Have you heard about [viewcomponent](https://viewcomponent.org/)s? They are easy and quick to test.

Comment: I have just recently learned about them, as the nonstandard ruby in rails controllers was bugging me. Maybe this will help you to get started: [copy-a-controller-class-instance-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66433139/copy-a-controller-class-instance-variables).

Comment: The comments about viewcomponents seem unrelated to what has been asked.

Answer (score 0):

Following is configuration from my `spec/rails_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.

  # References:
  #   https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/transactions
  #   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493970/databasecleaner-rspec-what-is-the-correct-configuration
  #   http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  # https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-example
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:suite) do
    begin
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    ensure
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end


  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

I am using the above since a long time in my years old project. May be you can try this out.

You can also see the references I have noted while I was exploring about using database_cleaner correctly. BTW in my application I am using `database_cleaner` having version `1.5.3`.

Hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. There are lots of tables and each time I run rspec, the load process truncate all the tables and, for each table, it takes an average of about 7 seconds.